# Jboss6.1 ClassNotFound in WEB/lib for listener

Tags: spring, jakarta-ee, jboss

I use jboss6.1. When I try to deploy a web app, it say class not found when try to load spring.

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

the error is

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener
```

I put the spring in WEB/lib. Is that wrong? Or should be something else?

---

Thanks for the kind replies. What confuses me is I put the spring jars in my webapp's WEB/lib folder. Isn't that enough?

---

Following are the web.xml and the jars. ( I put all I grabbed in the dist folder of spring3.1)

But I wonder maybe is because I use jboss and there's something special in it? I google some post class loader but don't understand.

---

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/jsp"
    xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="CMDB_WS_HOST" version="3.0">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>99999999</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <context-param> 
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.inspur.cmdb.system.StartupListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

---

spring jars in web/lib

org.springframework.aop-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.asm-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.aspects-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.beans-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.context.support-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.context-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.core-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.expression-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.instrument.tomcat-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.instrument-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.jdbc-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.jms-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.orm-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.oxm-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.test-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.transaction-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.web.portlet-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.web.servlet-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.web.struts-3.1.0.M2.jar

org.springframework.web-3.1.0.M2.jar

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using?
Can you post the jars in your classpath?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your server classpath has included the Spring jar library. In Spring 3 its, spring-web.jar

check whether you have these jars in WEB/lib

```
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
jstl-1.2.jar
spring-asm-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar
```

Comment: Ok, this is what confuses me. I put the spring jars in my webapp's WEB/lib folder. Isn't that enough?

Comment: thats fine. please list down all the jars in it and post the web.xml configurations as well

Comment: If you are not posting what you have configured entirely in web.xml, no one can say where you have gone wrong

Comment: Thank you @Swarnajith. I updated my question. I tried if I put the jars in jboss6.1/server/default/lib, then it can find them and no exception thrown. Only I put then under webapp/WEB-INF/lib exception is thrown. Btw, I am using eclipse3.7/JbossAs tool to run my application.

Comment: you don't need to put jars into "jboss6.1/server/default/lib"

Comment: I think the same at first. But the fact (try couple times) is: 1. it works if I put them in jboss6.1/server/default/lib 2. it doesn't if I put them in webapp/WEB-INF/lib

Answer (score 0):

It is ok with `JBoss 7`.It is `classloading` effect.

Config : `/WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC
    "-//JBoss//DTD Web Application 4.2//EN"
    "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_4_2.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
        <loader-repository>
                   myapp:loader=anyUniqueName
            <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
        </loader-repository>
    </class-loading>
</jboss-web>
```

**Otherwise**

I reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-framework/docs/3.2.0.M2/api/org/springframework/instrument/classloading/jboss/JBossLoadTimeWeaver.html).

I have not tried with `JBoss 6` yet. But, I hope, the following configuration will be helpful for `JBoss 6`.

**NOTE:**

On JBoss 6.0, to avoid the container loading the classes before the application actually starts, one needs to add a WEB-INF/jboss-scanning.xml file to the application archive - with the following content:

Config : `/WEB-INF/jboss-scanning.xml`

```
<scanning xmlns="urn:jboss:scanning:1.0"/>
```

Comment: @GaryX, please, revise answer again.

Comment: Thank you. I think it is close. I tried and still no luck. I will dig in it later.